# Java input array based on if/else using recursion only

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, recursion

I've been given the following homework...

- We have bunnies standing in a line, numbered 1, 2, ... n
- The even numbered bunnies (2, 4, ..) have the normal 2 ears.
- The odd numbered bunnies (1, 3, ..) have 3 ears.
- Recursively return the number of "ears" in the bunny line 1, 2, ... n (without loops or multiplication).

I tried first with loops:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BunnyEars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of bunnies: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int [] bunnies = new int [a];
        //for loop(non-recursive method)
        for(int i=0;i<bunnies.length;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0)
            {
                bunnies[i]=2;
            }
            else
            {
                bunnies[i]=3;
            }
            System.out.println("Bunny ["+i+"] : "+bunnies[i]+" ears");
        }
    }
}
```

However, after removing the loop, I'm not sure how to increment the array number as shown here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BunnyEars {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of bunnies: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int [] bunnies = new int [a];

        Ears(bunnies);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void Ears(int [] bunnies) {
        int x =0;
        bunnies[x]=bunnies[x+1];
        if(x<bunnies.length)
        {
            if(x%2==0)
            {
                bunnies[x]=2;
            }
            else
            {
                bunnies[x]=3;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Bunny ["+x+"] : "+bunnies[x]+" ears");
    }

}
```

I will keep getting just "bunny[0]: 2 ears". There is another bunny question on stackoverflow but the output desired is different. Been searching around but can't seem to find a similar question. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with the **pseudocode** below. I don't want to write real code because it's a homework assignment and you're supposed to learn from trial and error.

So here is the pseudocode. You'll have to figure out how to end the recursion.

```
int ears(int[] bunnies) {
  return Ears(bunnies, 0);
}

int ears(int[] bunnies, int index) {
    int ears = countEars(bunnies, index);
    return ears + ears(bunnies, index + 1);
}
```

Comment: This uses 2 methods right? Is it possible to have recursion using 1 method and no loops? Or having 2 variables mean that there has to be 2 methods?

Comment: I guess Tamas used two methods to separate output and recursion. You are not forced to use the extra method; it is just cleaner code. Mind that the example as is will throw an IndexOutOfRange exception (I know it's only pseudo, but IMO this must be addressed even there).

Comment: @Fildor indeed, end condition is missing. I skipped it **deliberately**. I mentioned it in the text: *"You'll have to figure out how to end the recursion."*

Comment: @bamboosymphony you can use one method. In that case, you need to use `Arrays.copyOfRange()`. That's more elegant, but it might need more resources due to the data copy.

Comment: sorry but can I clarify, is countEars another method i need to create?

Comment: @bamboosymphony it depends on you :) One option is to create a new method, another option is to inline the code that calculates the number of ears for the given position.

Answer (score -2):

```
public class BunnyEars {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number of bunnies: ");
        int a = in.nextInt();

        printEar(a - 1);
    }

    public static void printEar(int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            printEar(i - 1);
        }

        System.out.println("Bunny [" + i + "] : " + ((i % 2 == 0) ? 2 : 3) + " ears");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not just post uncommented code. This will probably end up flagged as "low quality".